# Textboxfor wont be sent to controller on submit of Html.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm missing something because the checked values won't be sent back to controller as the rest of my form does.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Tasks) 
<ul>
    @for(var i = 0; i < @Model.Tasks.Count; i++) 
    { 
        <li>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Tasks.ElementAt(i).Id) 
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Tasks.ElementAt(i).IsChecked) 
            @Model.Tasks.ElementAt(i).TaskName
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

.....

```
var taskItems = new List <TasksModel>();

foreach(var task in tasks) {
     taskItems.Add(new TasksModel(task.Id, task.Name, false));
 }

var viewModel = new CreateScheduleViewModel {
         Patients = patients,
         Employees = employees,
         PatientId = 0,
         EmployeeId = 0,
         Tasks = taskItems,
};

return View(viewModel);
```

Comment: Can you show part from your `TasksModel` in which you have thi `IsChecked`

Comment: You have found a limitation of MVC's HTML helpers. They do not know how to generate markup for `x.Tasks.ElementAt(i)`. It's time to learn how model binding works. Look up "model binding collections in MVC" on Google.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work now.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code. The name tag generated for the checkbox tag is responsible for model binding. A little change and your code will work fine.

Just change your 'for' loop in view as mentioned here---

```
 @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Tasks.Count; i++) // Not @Model.Tasks.Count
    {
        <li>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Tasks[i].Id) // Note
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Tasks[i].IsChecked) // Note
            @Model.Tasks.ElementAt(i).Name
        </li>  
    }
```

It is expected that your model is included ('CreateScheduleViewModel') in view. Run your code. It works fine !!!